# Probability of throwing two dice and getting one 3 / 5.

Tags: probability, dice

Imagine playing the game Yahtzee and you are going for a large straight ( every dice fits in, example: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$). On your first roll you get $1, 2$ and $3$ already, but you still need the $4$ & $5$. You have two rolls left. Now I want to know how big the probability is, that you get one $4$ and one $5$ in the next $2$ rolls.

I can't wrap my head around it. Even worse: I want to calculate the same thing for the case you get only $1$ and $2$ on your first throw and now you need a $3$, $4$ and $5$ in your next two throws...

If anybody has an idea let me know :)

Comment: Off topic: If you only rolled 1's and 2's, you'd have at least three of a kind in one of them... I'd think going for another yahtzee would be better than going for a lg. straight as most versions of the rules allow for bonus points if you get multiple yahtzees in the same game.

Comment: That said... try looking at smaller individual problems.  What is the probability you finish your lg. straight on the second roll?  What is the probability you make no progress on the second roll but then complete the lg. straight on the third?  Finally, find the chance you make progress by finding one of the numbers you needed but not both and then on the third roll you get the final missing number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint on first case:

There are $3$ mutually exclusive routes:

- in the first of the two rolls you throw a $4$ *and* a $5$
- in the first of the two rolls you throw exactly one of the numbers $4$ and $5$ and in the second of the two rolls you throw the other number.
- in the first of the two rolls you throw not a $4$ and not a $5$ and in the second you throw both.

Find the three corresponding probabilities. Then - because the routes are mutually exclusive - the summation of these probabilities is the answer.

---

**Edit** concerning the second problem (needed are $3$, $4$ and $5$ in at most two throws)

If $\hat{S}$ is a random set then for a finite set $S$ it can be
proved that: $$P\left(\hat{S}=S\right)=\sum_{T\subseteq S}P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq T\right)\left(-1\right)^{\left|S\right|-\left|T\right|}\tag1$$

This result shows up if we start with the observation that: $$P\left(\hat{S}=S\right)=P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq S\right)-P\left(\bigcup_{s\in S}\left\{ \hat{S}\subseteq S-\left\{ s\right\} \right\} \right)$$
and apply inclusion/exclusion on the second term on RHS.

Further if there is symmetry in the sense that probabilities like
$P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq T\right)$ only depend on the cardinality
of $T$ then $(1)$ can further be worked out, resulting in: $$P\left(\hat{S}=S\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\left|S\right|}\binom{\left|S\right|}{k}\left(-1\right)^{\left|S\right|-k}p_{k}\tag2$$
where $p_{k}$ stands for $P\left(\hat{S}\subseteq T\right)$ whenever
$\left|T\right|=k$.

If moreover $\hat{S}$ takes values in $\wp X$
where $\left|X\right|=m$ then we can deduce from $(2)$ easily that: $$P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=n\right)=\binom{m}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}p_{k}\tag3$$

Now let $D_{1},D_{2},D_{3}$ denote the outcomes of $3$ dice and
let: $$\hat{S}:=\left\{ D_{1},D_{2},D_{3}\right\} \cap\left\{ 3,4,5\right\} $$
Then we have the following expression for the probability that
you are seeking for:

$$P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=3\right)+P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=2\right)\frac{1}{6}+P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=1\right)\frac{2}{36}+P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=0\right)P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=3\right)\tag4$$
In this context we have:
$$p_{k}=\left(\frac{3+k}{6}\right)^{3}\text{ for }k=0,1,2,3$$and based on $(3)$ we find:

- $P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=0\right)=\binom{3}{0}p_{0}=\frac{27}{216}$
- $P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=1\right)=\binom{3}{1}\left(p_{1}-p_{0}\right)=3\left(\frac{64}{216}-\frac{27}{216}\right)=\frac{111}{216}$
- $P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=2\right)=\binom{3}{2}\left(p_{2}-2p_{1}+p_{0}\right)=3\left(\frac{125}{216}-\frac{128}{216}+\frac{27}{216}\right)=\frac{72}{216}$
- $P\left(\left|\hat{S}\right|=3\right)=\binom{3}{3}\left(p_{3}-3p_{2}+3p_{1}-p_{0}\right)=\frac{216}{216}-\frac{375}{216}+\frac{192}{216}-\frac{27}{216}=\frac{6}{216}$

Substituting these values in $(4)$ we find:

$$\frac{6}{216}+\frac{72}{216}\times\frac{1}{6}+\frac{111}{216}\times\frac{2}{36}+\frac{27}{216}\times\frac{6}{216}=\frac{5382}{46656}=\frac{299}{2592}$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it definitely helped, just for confirmation, the probability would look like this for the case i hit a 4 in the first and a 5 in the second, right?

(2/6) * (5/6) * (1/6)

My thought was that in the first throw [(2/6) * (5/6)] the probability to get one of the two needed numbers is 2/6. For the second dice, rolling a not needed number is now 5/6 instead of 4/6 because i already got one of the two needed numbers right before. In the last throw i have the 1/6 chance of getting the last remaining one.

Would this be a correct conclusion?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, you are right. Thank you, for attending me, I will delete my former comment.

Comment: Number the two dice. The probability that a 4 is rolled and not a
5 equals $P(D_{1}=4,D_{2}\neq5)+P(D_{1}\neq5,D_{2}=4)-P\left(D_{1}=4=D_{5}\right)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}$.
For the probability that a 5 is rolled and not a 4 we find the same
outcome. Their sum gives the probability that exactly one of the numbers
4,5 is rolled. To find the probability mentioned under the second
bullet this must be multiplied by $\frac16$ (i.e.
the probability that the last roll gives the number that is still
missing)

Comment: Alright i think i got that, but now i am struggling to use this kind of solution for the problem with 3 dices. I thougt of this:  
    P(D1=3,D2≠4||5, D3≠4||5) * 3 - P(D1 = D2 = D3 = 3) - P(D1 = D2 = 3, D3≠4,5) - P(D2 = D3 = 3, D1≠4,5) - P(D1 = D3 = 3, D2≠4,5) 
but i am definitely not sure. Is this correct?

Comment: I can imagine why you speak of "struggling". It is quite tricky. I have edited an answer to your second question.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!